# mysql select all records where ColumnA = X but ColumnA has no other value

Tags: mysql, unique, distinct, not-exists

I have a `usersTable` with a data set like the following:

```
+--------------------+------+
| user_ID            | ceID |
+--------------------+------+
| 20201011_557141020 | 1136 |
| 20201118_936245153 | 1113 |
| 20200224_856349817 | 1113 |
| 20201021_979024023 | 1139 |
| 20201021_979024023 | 1146 |
| 20201104_500741407 | 1139 |
| 20201021_979024023 | 1147 |
| 20201021_979024023 | 1113 |
| 20210412_238528636 | 1118 |
| 20220523_576943860 | 1113 |
| 20220523_576943860 | 1119 |
| 20220522_893258175 | 1119 |
+--------------------+------+
```

I need to select all users where ceID=1113 and do not have any other entries where ceID equals another value.

All users where ceID=1113:

```
+--------------------+------+
| user_ID            | ceID |
+--------------------+------+
| 20201118_936245153 | 1113 |
| 20200224_856349817 | 1113 |
| 20201021_979024023 | 1113 |
| 20220523_576943860 | 1113 |
+--------------------+------+
```

But the desired results should be:

```
+--------------------+------+
| user_ID            | ceID |
+--------------------+------+
| 20201118_936245153 | 1113 |
| 20200224_856349817 | 1113 |
+--------------------+------+
```

Because users `20201021_979024023` and `20220523_576943860` do have other entries where ceID does equal something else.

I have tried this, which isn't working, and don't understand why nor I have I been able to think of another query to do this:

```
 select user_ID from clubUsers where ceID=1113 and not exists (select user_ID clubUsers where ceID != 1113) ;
```

Comment: output seems to be the same as desired output, see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=040a0031e232340ad9137abf644dc42d) (when you select  two fields, and not just one...

Comment: and the answer from Tim is also correct, see [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b62ea430f1c7ce5882d2f4be11ee184c)

Comment: yes, it is correct.  I recreated a test table in my own db and the query works. but against the real table its not working.  i have analyzed all the basics between the tables and everything is the same (column types, etc).  Really scratching my head on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregation is one straightforward option:

```sql
SELECT user_ID
FROM clubUsers
GROUP BY user_ID
HAVING MIN(ceID) = MAX(ceID)  -- min/max ceID the same => only 1 value
       AND MIN(ceID) = 1113;  -- that single value is 1113
```

Comment: thanks, I tried this query but it returned zero results.

Comment: ...my answer is correct.  I question either your data or perhaps you copied it wrongly.

Comment: not to argue with you, but the data sets are correct and I copied your query verbatim.  The provided data sets are straight out of my clubUsers table, not manually created data.

Comment: @rolinger *I tried this query but it returned zero results* [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=19cb3dfb0d5d49847215e2b128a014ba) - your sample data, Tim's query, your desired output. Be more accurate simply.

Comment: @Akina - well, that does prove it.  Marking answer as correct, not certain why I am not getting the same results though.

Comment: figured it out, it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Hello please try this one:

```
SELECT T1.user_id FROM
(select user_ID, COUNT(user_ID)
from clubUsers
where ceID=1113
GROUP BY user_ID) AS T1 
INNER JOIN(select user_ID, COUNT(user_ID) from clubUsers GROUP BY user_ID HAVING COUNT(user_ID) = 1) AS T2
    ON T1.user_ID = T2.user_ID;
```

If we execute the query then:
[image: Click to see image]

Comment: How is your query better/different than (the simple query): `SELECT  T1.user_id FROM  (select user_ID, COUNT(user_ID) from clubUsers  where ceID=1113   GROUP BY user_ID  HAVING count(*)=1) AS T1 ` ? (see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=884b9a53511f07db74a446b9b268f20d))

Comment: @Luuk your result set looks different in me. It does not produce the intended output.

Comment: You did look at the output of the dbfiddle, did you ?

Comment: I can see your query here.

Comment: I think you need to [edit] your answer, and add some explanation on why you think that "this one" is better than any other give answers here.

Comment: This one is not better than the other. In fact 1.35 times slower than the other one. It is only a different approach.